# Cannot use EF Core Migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, autofac, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core code first in a window service with Autofac DI and when I run Add-Migration TestDD1InitialMigration I get error

```
No parameterless constructor was found on 'ClientsContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'ClientsContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory<ClientsContext>' in the same assembly as 'ClientsContext'.
```

How can I avoid this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try following the advice of the error? That seems like the most straightforward thing to do.

Comment: See http://benjii.me/2016/05/dotnet-ef-migrations-for-asp-net-core/ point 3

Comment: @mike If I try what it suggests I need to add connectionstring as hard coded. That is something that you need to avoid

Comment: @Milen again this requires to create a factory with hard coded connstring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a context factory so EF Core can create a DbContext for migrations:

```
public class MyDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

    public MyDbContextFactory()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        _configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public MyDbContext Create()
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), m => { m.EnableRetryOnFailure(); });

        return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

And an `appsettings.json` file where you put your connection string:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "<your_connection_string>"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Only change is Create method signature is different

Comment: Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)